# Redirect to delete on confirm button Angular

Tags: angularjs

When I click 'Delete' button confirmation dialog appears. If response is yes I want to delete review (redirect to `deleteReview`) and refresh page, if answer is no I want to cancel dialog. But I am not sure how to redirect it correctly.

I have this method which appears after clicking delete button:

```
$scope.showConfirm = function(ev,index) {
// Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('Would you like to delete your review?')
      .textContent('Your review will be deleted.')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Yes')
      .cancel('No');debugger;

    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() { 
  //IF YES redirect to deleteReview and refresh page
    }, function() {
   //IF NO cancel
    });
};
```

this is my deleteReview function:

```
 $scope.redirectDelete = function(index){debugger;
        $scope.all[index].id; console.log($scope.all[index].id);debugger;
        var JSONObject={
            "id":$scope.all[index].id
        }

        var Results = UniversalService.DeleteReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));debugger

    };
```

And this is html button:

`<md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-click="showConfirm($event,$index)" > Delete </md-button>`

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page? angular power is in creating single page applications, with no need to reload the page when some data is changed. You can get the comments from the server and store them in `$scope.comments`, when you need to delete a comment just remove it from the array and post to your server to delete it from DB, so on next page reload it will of course be gone as well.

Answer (score 1):

Call `$scope.redirectDelete(index);` from the promise callback, but also add `$scope.all.splice(index,1);` to your `redirectDelete` method to remove it from your client-side array.

Ideally, you'd splice the value out of the array on the client-side only *after* it was successfully removed on the server-side. This is usually done by calling the `splice` code when the server promise is resolved, but I'm not sure what your `UniversalService.DeleteReview` method returns. If it's a promise, then it'd look like this:

```
UniversalService.DeleteReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject)).then(function(results)
    $scope.all.splice(index,1);
});
```

AngularJS will see that the array was modified and refresh the view automatically for you. No need to manually refresh the page.